# Meteor React Form

Tags: meteor, meteor-react

I'm trying to render a form with data stored in the database. If I remove the form and wrap the `PositionSingle` **input** fields in a **div** the data renders correctly however I'm unable to make any changes. When I wrap the inputs in a **form** the component doesn't render.

I'm new to react with meteor so any assitance is appreciated.

Path: `PositionSingle.jsx`

```
render() {
    return (    
        <form className="new-position" onSubmit={this.addPosition.bind(this)}>
            <input 
                type="text" 
                ref="title"
                placeholder="Position title" 
                defaultValue={this.props.position.title} />


            <input 
                type="text" 
                ref="company"
                placeholder="Company"
                defaultValue={this.props.position.company} />       

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Path: `PositionWrapper.jsx`

```
render() {

    return (
        <div>
            {this.positions().map( (position)=>{
                return  <PositionSingle key={position._id} position={position} />
            })}             
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: there must be an exception when rendering the form. You need to open the `Chrome Developer Tools` or `Firebug` console to see it

Comment: Exception from Tracker recompute function:TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Comment: do you have the `addPosition` function in `PositionSingle` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very old question, so I don't know if you still have the same project, even, but I like to make sure there are no loose ends if I can. That error looks like what @ThaiTran said, that you don't have `addPosition` defined in `PositionSingle`. After you add that, that error should go away. Did that work?